# Unique value checks

Tags: pandas

I used this code:  df['state'].unique()  to check unique value. This doesn't look good. Any better way to show the unique value? Anyone can help me? Thanks.

array(['WV', 'MT', 'GA', 'NC', 'TN', 'OH', 'HI', 'SC', 'WI', 'ID', 'SD',
'IL', 'NE', 'MS', 'NH', 'UT', 'MA', 'VT', 'NV', 'AL', 'US', 'MO',
'GU', 'WY', 'PR', 'ND', 'ME', 'AR', 'AK', 'KY', 'IA', 'MI', 'NY',
'LA', 'CT', 'RI', 'DE', 'OK', 'NJ', 'KS', 'VI', 'AZ', 'DC', 'MD',
'CO', 'TX', 'MN', 'CA', 'IN', 'PA', 'FL', 'NM', 'VA'], dtype=object)

Comment: What's wrong with `df['state'].unique()`? You can also use `sorted(df['state'].unique())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'states': sorted(['WV', 'WV', 'AK', 'AK', 'AK', 'MT', 'GA', 'NC', 'TN', 'OH', 'HI', 'SC', 'WI', 'ID', 'SD', 'IL', 'NE', 'MS', 'NH', 'UT', 'MA', 'VT', 'NV', 'AL', 'US', 'MO', 'GU', 'WY', 'PR', 'ND', 'ME', 'AR', 'AK', 'KY', 'IA', 'MI', 'NY', 'LA', 'CT', 'RI', 'DE', 'OK', 'NJ', 'KS', 'VI', 'AZ', 'DC', 'MD', 'CO', 'TX', 'MN', 'CA', 'IN', 'PA', 'FL', 'NM', 'VA'])})
>>> 
>>> len(df.states)
57
>>> df.states.unique()
array(['AK', 'AL', 'AR', 'AZ', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DC', 'DE', 'FL', 'GA',
       'GU', 'HI', 'IA', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'KS', 'KY', 'LA', 'MA', 'MD',
       'ME', 'MI', 'MN', 'MO', 'MS', 'MT', 'NC', 'ND', 'NE', 'NH', 'NJ',
       'NM', 'NV', 'NY', 'OH', 'OK', 'PA', 'PR', 'RI', 'SC', 'SD', 'TN',
       'TX', 'US', 'UT', 'VA', 'VI', 'VT', 'WI', 'WV', 'WY'], dtype=object)
```

> This doesn't look good.

I disagree.
This seems to be the ideal way to express Author's Intent,
to express the notion of eliding duplicates.
I recommend calling `.unique()` for such a use case.